# Visual Studio Tools For Git VS Git Source control provider

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2012

I want to use `git` for my visual studio project , when I googled I found these two tools which integrate in Visual studio.

[Visual Studio Tools For Git](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c)
 and [Git Source control provider](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/63a7e40d-4d71-4fbb-a23b-d262124b8f4c)

I want to know which is better to use.

Comment: Microsoft recently added support for Git and i think no such question ask before. how my question is duplicate?

Comment: This is perfectly valid question. Seriously. He is asking *what are the differences* between Visual Studio Tools For Git and Git Source control provider. The link provided DOES NOT answer this question.

Comment: This is a valid question. not duplicated. please reopen.